# Why do I get the error "failed unmounting /var" during shutdown?

Tags: debian, partition, shutdown, unmounting, var

I have a fresh install of Debian 9.0.0. It has a separate 1 GB partition for /var formatted at ext4. When I shutdown from the terminal, using `shutdown -h now`, there is a bright-red error message stating "failed unmounting /var".

What is the fix for this error?

Comment: Seems like a common bug.  Is it still shutting down successfully afterwards?

Comment: It does appear to shutdown after the error is displayed.

Comment: When I googled it I found a few Ubuntu and Kali users experiencing the same issue and many people were chiming in that they saw the same thing but it didn't seem to affect anything.

Answer (score 13):

## The problem is `journald`

Or rather how it is still logging to `/var` while `systemd` is trying to unmount it.

### Solutions

According to [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=154144), there are two ways to go about it:

1. Make `journald` log to a volatile location in `/run` so it doesn't lock `/var`, but the tradeoff is that you lose logs at shutdown.

Edit `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` to change the `Storage=` line to

`Storage=volatile`

This is what I did, and I it worked for me.

2. (EDIT: this is ArchLinux-specific) Or set up a shutdown hook to unmount `/var` later. This won't remove the `failed` message as systemd will still try to unmount `/var` but will indeed unmount `/var` properly at the end of the shutdown sequence. You just won't see it. (I haven't tested that solution though)

Add a `shutdown` hook to `mkinitcpio`'s `HOOKS=` array, e.g. :

`HOOKS="base udev autodetect block keymap encrypt lvm2 filesystems usbinput fsck var shutdown"`

Comment: I have two laptops with Ubuntu (one with a single HDD and one with HDD+SSD) and I got that annoying error message only on the second. In the second laptop, `/var` is in a different partition from `/` (`/` is in the SSD and `/var` is in the HDD) and, in the first laptop, `/var` is within `/`. This might play a role in the problem.

Comment: Indeed: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1204644#p1204644

Comment: A variant of topic (1) is to leave `Storage=auto` in journald.conf and just remove /var/log/journal. This worked for me, too, and journald logs are done to /run/log/journal/, instead. See `man journald.conf`.

Comment: `mkinitcpio` is specific to Arch, so your option 2) needs to be implemented in some other way in Debian.

Comment: @telcoM Okay thanks. I don't use Arch anymore, but I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to thank @Thibault Lemaire for pointing me to the right cause. I successfully resolved the error by applying these changes to `systemd-journald.service`:

```
...
[Unit]
...
After:umount.target
Conflicts=umount.target
```

Basically all(?) mounts (including /var) will be unmounted by umount.target, so if we stop systemd-journald before starting umount.target we can fix the error.